# Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource

Tags: node.js, permissions, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

In the GCP console, I created a service account and assigned a custom role to it which has the following permissions, note the bolded permission:

- **iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken**
- storage.buckets.get
- storage.multipartUploads.abort
- storage.multipartUploads.create
- storage.multipartUploads.list
- storage.multipartUploads.listParts
- storage.objects.create
- storage.objects.delete
- storage.objects.list

On my workstation, I followed the directions to authenticate with Application Default Credentials (ADC) using the gCloud CLI.

Here is my principal with Name and Role columns from IAM:

[IAM screen capture of principal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrY33.png)

`./gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=principle_email_address_here`

Here is my reference test function:

```
export async function createBucket(
  projectId: string,
  tenantExtId: string
): Promise<undefined> {
  const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: projectId
  });

  const result = await storage.createBucket(tenantExtId);
  console.dir(result);
  return;
}
```

I have a Jest unit test that attempts to validate the creation of a storage bucket. It is failing with the following msg:

```
#createBucket › creates a bucket name
    
Could not refresh access token: PERMISSION_DENIED: unable to impersonate: Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
```

I review the GCP docs and SO entries several times, and still do not know what I am doing wrong. This should have resulted in the creation of a new bucket name.

Comment: show the test code. Which identity is the CLI `gcloud` configured with? Does it have permission to use the service account (impersonate)?

Comment: @JohnHanley I provided the function under test as you requested. Based on the GCP ADC documentation, I can use the service account directly, as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/client-libraries#adc) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#gcloud-credentials). However, did I miss something? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnHanley I also added a screen capture of the IAM row of the principal identity.

Comment: The screenshot does not show anything relevant. The IAM identity must have permission to impersonate the service account. Your answer removes impersonation so that is not a solution to the problem you posted.

Comment: I do not disagree with you assessment and my "just get it working" answer. My question to you is what is the IAM permission, other than the permissions listed above, do I need to grant to the principal identity? Thanks.

Comment: You have granted permission to the service account not the identity that will use the service account.

Answer (score 3):

You, Person X, are trying to impersonate a service account. You have to grant yourself (i.e. Person X i.e. your gcloud user account) the *service account get access token* permission. You haven't yet done that. What you did was to grant that permission to the service account itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Ensuring that the Service Account I'm impersonating also has the `Service Account Token Creator` role** was the solution that worked for me in addition to @NoCommandLine's answer ([see docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#sa-impersonation)):

> You must have the Service Account Token Creator (roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator) IAM role on the service account you are impersonating. For more information, see [Required](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/use-service-account-impersonation#required-roles) roles.

And there it says:

> To ensure that the principal has the necessary permission to impersonate a service account, ask your administrator to **grant the principal the Service Account Token Creator (roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator) IAM role on the service account.**